# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) When Characters Exceed

Tags: ios, swift, exception, type-conversion

I know there are answers available regarding this exception but nothing is working for me.

My code was working fine where I have to convert the text of a textfield into `Int`, but now I noticed that when I enter more than 10 characters it crashes.

I have set character limit of those text fields to 11, but it is crashing on the last number with the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Here is the code

```
@IBAction func Qty_EndEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    print("For Total Cost")
    if QtyText.text != ""{
        if UnitPriceText.text != "" {
            TotalCostText.text = String((QtyText.text?.numberValue)! * (UnitPriceText.text?.numberValue)!)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func UnitPrice_EndEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    print("For Total Cost")
    if QtyText.text != ""{
        if UnitPriceText.text != "" {
         TotalCostText.text = String((QtyText.text?.numberValue)! * (UnitPriceText.text?.numberValue)!)  
 // CRASHING ON THE ABOVE LINE   
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var numberValue:Int? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter.number(from: self) as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `QtyText` and `UnitPriceText`? What is the implementation of your `numberValue` string property?

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to properly work with optionals. Combining `?` with `!` really makes no sense.

Comment: @YannickLoriot These are two textFields and through numberValue i'm getting Int from String.

Comment: @YannickLoriot And It's only crashing when the last (11th) character is entered in the text field, else it is calculating fine and showing result in the TotalCost field

Comment: @rmaddy And I understand about the optionals but the text fields were not empty that's why i was force unwrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is related to the fact that `Int` multiplication cannot handle such numbers, use `Double`.

Both of your actions do the same thing, try to place code that will be reused inside a `func`.

You also need to look at optionals and how to use them. Here's an example.

```
func updateTotalCost() {
    if let quantity = Double(QtyText.text ?? ""),
        let unitPrice = Double(UnitPriceText.text ?? "") {
        TotalCostText.text = String(quantity * unitPrice)
    } else {
        // ???
        TotalCostText.text = ""
    }
}

@IBAction func Qty_EndEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    updateTotalCost()
}

@IBAction func UnitPrice_EndEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    updateTotalCost()
}
```

I'll dissect some of it:

`QtyText.text ?? ""` -> If QtyText.text is nil, replace it with an empty string, otherwise use the value in QtyText.text

`Double(QtyText.text ?? "")` -> Build an `Double     from a`String`, which is guaranteed non-nil (since we forced it to be an empty`String`, even in the case the QtyText.text was nil)

This `Double()` constructor may, itself, return nil if the string passed to the constructor does not evaluate to a valid `Double` (for example, the `String` "abcd" cannot evaluate to an `Double`). Therefore, we wrap this in an `if let` statement to protect ourselves against the `Double()` constructor failing to build an `Double` from our `String`:

```
    if let quantity = Int(QtyText.text ?? "")
```

This is telling the compiler:

> Only evaluate this as true if what I'm placing in the quantity variable is not nil.

Finally, we chain two if statements with a comma:

```
    if let quantity = Int(QtyText.text ?? ""),
        let unitPrice = Int(UnitPriceText.text ?? "") {
```

Inside this part of the `if` statement, we'll be guaranteed that quantity and unitPrice both are valid `Doubles` , and that we can perform the calculation.

I’m not sure you’ll be please with the result of `String(myDoubleNumber)` but then you should look into number formatting to get what you want.

Comment: It's still crashing on the line where I'm multiplying,  TotalCostText.text = String(quantity * unitPrice) with same exception!

Comment: And I understand about the optionals but the text fields were not empty that's why i was force unwrapping.

Comment: And It's only crashing when the last (11th) character is entered in the text field, else it is calculating fine and showing result in the TotalCost field.

Comment: You are crashing because you’re overflowing what Int is capable of handling. Use Double instead. I’ve edited my answer.

Comment: So stupid of me i totally forgot about that, was trying to use Int64 instead, my bad. Thanks.